# Extend a DataObject in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

I installed a photogallery module in SilverStripe. This module has a DataObject named PhotoItem.

The PhotoItem class contains some fields, but I want to add extra fields. The easiest way to do that is to edit the PhotoItem file, but then I lose my changes when updating the module.

How can I extend this DataObject with some more fields with a DataObject file under /mysite/code?

Answer (score 3):

In Silverstripe 3.1 you can extend a class by creating a [`DataExtension`](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataextension) and applying it to your class.

First you would create a *CustomPhotoItem.php* in *mysite/code* or *mysite/code/extensions*:

**CustomPhotoItem.php**

```
class CustomPhotoItem extends DataExtension {

    private static $db = array(
        'ExtraTextField' => 'Text'
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        $fields->push(TextField::create('ExtraTextField', 'Extra Text Field'));
    }
}
```

In order to apply this extension to your class, you need to add the following to your [*config.yml*](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/configuration):

**config.yml**

```
PhotoItem:
  extensions:
    - CustomPhotoItem
```

Your config.yml should be located in *mysite/_config/config.yml*.

Run `dev/build?flush=1` and you should see your new variables added to your original object.

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly this, the new field has been added to the table PhotoItem, but the form field doesn't appaer in the cms.

Comment: Is [this the module](https://github.com/andrewhoule/silverstripe-photogallery) you were using for the Photo Gallery? If so, try using `$fields->push(new TextField('ExtraTextField', 'Extra Text Field'))` instead of `addFieldToTab`.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't work. I also opened an issue at Github and the developer of the module experience the same issue. very strange :( https://github.com/andrewhoule/silverstripe-photogallery/issues/4

Comment: I added my comment to the PR as to why its not working. (No call to parent::getCMSFields() which invokes updateCMSFields()).

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for DataExtension. Have a look to the [documentation](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/dataextension), there's evereything you need for adding some more fields to DataObjects.
In particular have a look to the section named **Adding extra database fields**